# Does the bulk write operation in DynamoDB utilize a multi-threading strategy?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I'm writing entries into a DynamoDB table:

```
import time
...

for item in my_big_map.items():
    Ddb_model(column1=item[0], column2=item[1], column_timestamp=time.time()).save()
```

I suspect this is slow so I was thinking about using a multi-threading strategy such as `concurrent.futures` to write each entry to the table:

```
def write_one_entry(item):
    Ddb_model(column1=item[0], column2=item[1], column_timestamp=time.time()).save()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(write_one_entry, my_big_map.items())
```

However, I've found this way of doing [batch writes](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html#batch-writes) in PynamoDB's documentation. It looks like it's a handy way to accelerate write operation.

Does it also use a multi-threading strategy?

Is the PynamoDB implementation better than using `concurrent.futures` to do bulk writes?

Comment: Doesn't answer your Q but - why don't you use the SDK?

Comment: I’m working on an established package written by previous engineer. I don’t have context why Pynamo was chosen. If I switch to SDK, it will be a serious refactoring project…any reason I should switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect this is slow

**Correct, you're not taking advantage of the `BatchWriteItem` API which allows you to write up to 16 MB of data (or a max of 25 creation/delete requests).**

It is essentially a bulk of `PutItem` and/or `DeleteItem` requests (*note that you cannot update an item via `BatchWriteItem` however*). Not using this API means that you are losing out on performance & network improvements that come with AWS combining the update operations in one go.

---

> Does it also use a multi-threading strategy?

No, it doesn't need to particularly - an interface to the bulk API is all that is needed.

**The main speed improvement will come from batch processing on AWS's side, not locally.**

---

> Is the PynamoDB implementation better than using `concurrent.futures` to do bulk writes?

Yes because it is important that the bulk API is actually used, not how the data is iterated, for the maximum benefit.

**Your `concurrent.futures` implementation will be faster than your original code but still doesn't take advantage of the `BatchWriteItem` API.** You are speeding up how you're calling AWS but you're still sending a request per item in `my_big_map.items()` and that is what will be taking up the most time.

PynamoDB seems to be using the bulk API from taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/blob/master/pynamodb/models.py#L98) regardless of whether you use [context managers or iterators](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html) so you will be better off using the PynamoDB implementation which will also handle pagination of items etc. for you under the hood.

---

**The important part is that you use the `BatchWriteItem` API, which will give you the speed improvement you are looking for.**

PynamoDB's batch writing will let you do this (as well as AWS's [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing)).